# Powershell Send-MailMessage cmdlet - Subject parameter won't let me pass a number

Tags: windows, powershell, system-administration

So as part of a larger script I'm working on I have to send an email with results
Whenever I use a number in the Subject field not only is the number not send BUT the mailmessage is never sent and no error message appears. I used try / catch even for haha's but there are not errors to be caught, it's quite perplexing. Anyone else ever run into this problem?
If I use alphabetical characters it functions fine, but numbers seem to cause issues :-/

```
Send-MailMessage -SmtpServer("mailserver.fakecorp.com") -From("Nagios.Monitor@fakecorp.com") -To("Adamk@fakecorp.com") -Subject("30") -Body("$arrProbURLs")
```

Comment: Hmm, that's quite strange.  Any chance it's the SMTP server that's not sending the mail?

Comment: Follow these commands with the telnet client to test the SMTP server: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/153119

Comment: And what happends if you specify parameter values the normal PowerShell way? `Send-MailMessage -SmtpServer "mailserver.fakecorp.com"  -From "Nagios.Monitor@fakecorp.com" -To "Adamk@fakecorp.com" -Subject "30" -Body "$arrProbURLs"`

Comment: Apparently it's my email false alarm. I tried from my the pc of the cubicle over and it worked. Something with my email. Ok powershell's not the problem :) I thought that would have been quite strange! Thanks for the quick responses!

Comment: I'm an idiot... they were going into my junk mail box. Time to turn in my IT card :(

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it's my email false alarm. I tried from my the pc of the cubicle over and it worked. Something with my email. Ok powershell's not the problem :) I thought that would have been quite strange! Thanks for the quick responses!